# how to reference previous arguments of a function call in later arguments?

Tags: python, micropython

*This is in micropython*

I'm creating an API to control some hardware. The API will be implemented in C with an interface in micropython.

One example of my API is:

```
device.set(curr_chan.BipolarRange, curr_chan.BipolarRange.state.ON)
```

I'd like to be able to achieve the same functionality but shorten the second path by *somehow* implicitly referencing the first argument:

```
device.set(curr_chan.BipolarRange, <first arg?>.state.ON)
```

**Is there anyway to do this?**

The only way to do *something* like this now would be

```
device.set(curr_chan.BipolarRange.state.ON)
```

and then put an upward pointing C-pointer on both the `ON` C-object and `state` C-object so that I know which entry in `curr_chan` is being referenced.

The micropython runtime - and I assume CPython one - doesn't keep the entire object "tree" available to the developer in memory.

Comment: You might only have to put something referencing the `BipolarRange` on `ON` and not on `state`, but yeah, that works if you need the API to look like that.

Comment: @Ry- Could I use a decorator to implicitly pre-pend `arg1` to `argN`?

Comment: If you could find some satisfying way to represent `.state.ON`, sure. Strings are messy and inefficient, lambdas aren’t fantastic, I don’t know what works in micropython…

Answer (score 1):

You could have special values for the second (state) argument which tell the function implementation to derive the state from the first argument.  You could also introduce a completely separate function which has this behavior.

Or you could have a helper function which determines the state and passes it down to the `set` function, something like this:

```
device.set(*state_ON(curr_chan.BipolarRange))
```

Here, `state_ON` would return a tuple `(curr_chan.BipolarRange, curr_chan.BipolarRange.state.ON)`.

In any case, there is no direct support for what you are trying to do in Python itself.

Comment: What about decorator?

Comment: That's just a special case of having a second function with the deriving behavior.

Comment: And that's an acceptable answer. I'm making this API for NON-programmers. I want it to be simple for them.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the *name* of the attribute you want as the second argument. Call [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) (or [`PObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) repeatedly to get each element of the `.`-separated string:

```
device.set(curr_chan.BipolarRange, 'state.ON')
```